# filter datagridview to show all data

Tags: vb.net

I currently have a combo box which when selected shows each vehicles data by Vehicle reg which is what I want, but how do  I make it show all data again after?

Here is the code

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.SelectionChangeCommitted

    If cnn.State = System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed Then
        cnn.Open()
    End If
    Dim sqlquery As String = "select vehiclereg,datereported,defects1,repaired1,defects2,repaired2,defects3,repaired3,datefixed1,datefixed2,datefixed3 from vehicledefects WHERE vehiclereg like '" & Me.ComboBox2.Text & "%'"

    Dim sqlcommand As New OleDbCommand
    Dim sqladapter As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim table As New DataTable
    With sqlcommand
        .CommandText = sqlquery
        .Connection = cnn
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With
    With sqladapter
        .SelectCommand = sqlcommand
        .Fill(table)
    End With

    Dim ds As New DataSet
    sqladapter.Fill(ds, "VehicleDefects")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    cnn.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Build the DataTable without the WHERE clause in the SQL.  Use DefaultView.RowFilter to filter it to a subset, remove the filter when done with it.  Having the filter in the SQL means you'd have to re run the query to remove the filter.

Comment: sorry, I'm quite new to VB, would you mind giving me the code.